# Akka actor system 2.6 usage in a Play framework REST service

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-actor

I have a REST service which has multiple actors co ordinate with each-other. The data is stored in postgresDB. 
As per the new akka actor system 2.6 for typed actors, https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/typed/actors.html, we need to pass messages between actors and based on the message the actors respond. 
E.g. I have to do CRUD operations for user categories. 
The Request flow is:
Controller -> Actor 1 -> Actor 2 -> DAO
The Response flow is:
DAO -> Actor 2 -> Actor 1 -> Controller

Based on this scenario, I have a few questions:

1 Do we have to have different onMessages for each actor?

```
return newReceiveBuilder().onMessage(GetCategories.class, this::onGet)
.onMessage(AddCategories.class, this::onAdd)
.build();
```

2. How will the controller call the actor 1?
3. Do we need a new POJO for each message being passed? E.g. GetCategory, AddCategory.
4. Isn't this too much of code setup in each actor?